# Post validation of webjobs needs to start if not start already

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-webjobs

Now, I have the script to start the webjobs and check the status whether it is running or not.If not running the webjobs(continuous,triggered) I need to wait for a moment to check again and if not running I need to start those jobs which are not running.For accomplish this task,I need power shell script.Can anyone help me out on this ?

Comment: Sorry can you be more specific on what you try to achieve ? Do you have to use powershell ? Could you use `TimerTrigger` rather than restarting job ? Any other usefull information will be great

Comment: I just need to check the all the web jobs properly running or not once after the deployment of webApp in azure,start web jobs step. Usually I am doing stop webApp service-stop webjobs-deploy web app-start web job-start web app service.. After the above steps done I need to check whether all the webjobs are properly running or not. That's it. I need any power shell script for the validation.

Comment: What plugin is available in vsts for the webjobs validation

Comment: What is time trigger which you mentioned. Is us plugin or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is right, maybe you could try following script.

```
$ResourceGroupName=""
$AppService=""
$Apiversion=""
##ContinuousWebJobs
$continuejob=Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceName $AppService -ResourceType Microsoft.web/sites/ContinuousWebJobs -ApiVersion $Apiversion 
$status=$continuejob.Properties.status
#$status='Running'
$j=1
while($j -le 5)
{
     if($status -ne 'Running')
     {
        $continuejob=Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceName $AppService -ResourceType Microsoft.web/sites/ContinuousWebJobs -ApiVersion $Apiversion 
        $status=$continuejob.Properties.status
        $j+=1 
        "waiting for running, will sleep 6s..."
        sleep 6
     }else{
        Write-Host "already running, exit this script" -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor Green
        sleep 6 
        quit
     }
}
Write-Host  "Error:waiting for 30s already, The job is not running" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Red
```

If your job is not running, wait for 6s and test again.

Comment: I didn't test yet. I will let you know by tomorrow. Thanks much.

Comment: Bro, can you help me on deploying table data into table storage.I have opened new thread Please help me on that. Below is the link. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091334/best-approach-to-deploy-tables-into-table-storage

Comment: @PDBRPRAVEEN Sorry, I am not good at this, I think Azure support team will help you.

Comment: Do you have any contact of them. I will approach directly.

Comment: Now,I have a requirement like,if continuous jobs are not  in running status by validate with the above script even after checking for 30 seconds  I need to fail this script or task.So that I will come to know that the jobs are not running.We can check the  status in the log but I if I fail the script or task then I will come to know the jobs are not running.So,How can we do that? One more thing ,after each build or release job fails,VSTS should trigger the mails to all my team members.How can I do this one?

Comment: @PDBRPRAVEEN Hi, this is a VSTS problem. Maybe you could ask a new question about this.

Comment: At least you can please help me with the failed part, if webjobs are not running even after checking the status for 30 seconds I need that script to be failed. How can I do this?

Comment: @PDBRPRAVEEN I update my answer, maybe you could check. If the script runs successful, it will quit the script, if it fail, it will print error log.

Comment: I am facing one issue here,Suppose I have 4 continuous webjobs,among them 2 jobs are running and 2 jobs are not running.I started the webjobs and after that your script will check whether the webjobs are properly started or not.Suppose at this case,2 of my webjobs are taking time to start.At this case,Will your script should check the status for every 6 secs and fail the step.?. Because only 2 jobs are running but your script is checking only first value of $status and coming out and saying running.Its not taking the status of all the webjobs.

Comment: Assume like ,the $status variable is having values running running stop stop.for the 4 continuous web jobs.Please tell me how to solve this issue as I tried this script its checking only first value of $status variable and saying output running even though 2 jobs are not running.

Comment: Hi, could you use different VSTS tasks to check different jobs?

Comment: I didn't get you.Could you please tell me clearly.As I told you,$status variable is holding the status of 4 web jobs.Upon checking the condition in the above script :if($status -ne 'Running')..Its checking only the first webjob status and not checking the other 3 webjobs status and going into the loop as its assuming all the webjobs are running but only one webjob is running.How to accomplish this task.Please share modify the script and share to me.Or tell me the steps I will go ahead and add the tasks.

Comment: @PDBRPRAVEEN Sorry, I also don't know how to do it. Maybe you could ask a new question with your requirement. It will help you solve this issue faster. :--)

Comment: Thanks Walter.Let me check with somebody.